# Isn't lībra pondō pleonastic? Because both lībra and pondō meant "weight"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Isn't *lībra pondō*  [redundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics)#Rhetoric), [pleonastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) and [tautological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language))? Because both lībra and  pondō meant "weight"? See below!

Wikipedia translates *lībra pondō* as  ["("the weight measured in libra"), in which the word *pondo* is the ablative singular of the Latin noun *pondus* ("weight")"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)#Etymology).

#### Etymology of *libra*

[Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121269) wrote that *libra*

> [originally meant ‘stone’, thence ‘pound weight’ (i.e., the little stone you put on scales to weigh things), thence ‘pound’ (the weight of one of those stones), and only from that was the meaning generalised to mean ‘weight’ in general.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121269)

[Tim Lymington wrote that *librum* meant "'weight' as an abstract concept."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121270)

["You will also know *Libra* as the astrological sign, the seventh sign of the zodiac. In classical times that name was given to rather an uninspiring constellation, with no particularly bright stars in it. It was thought to represent scales or a balance, the main sense of *libra* in Latin, which is why it is often accompanied by the image of a pair of scales."](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pou1.htm)

["It's from Latin *libra*, an ancient Roman unit of weight, likely from Proto-Italic **liθra*."](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/32evcd/why_do_we_abbreviate_pound_as_lb_when_it_contains/cqaknt2/)

#### Etymology of *pondō*

["*pondo* in Latin is the ablative of *pondus*, which is literally 'weight' (ablative being 'by weight')."](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/d3z71e/til_that_pounds_are_abbreviated_to_lbs_because_it/f065749/)

### How do these quotations below  distinguish *lībra* vs. *pondō*?

In my research, I stumbled these quotations below. But what do they mean? Are they relevant?

["It makes more sense if you explain that "**l**i**b**ra", which meant "balance" is the actual word that came to mean the unit of weight. The "pondo" part precised the weight. "](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/26ksv0/til_the_latin_phrase_libra_pondo_was_used_in/chs46y9/)

> [“a pound by weight” as opposed to a pound by what other measure?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/9a81nt/why_is_pounds_abbreviated_as_lbs/e4ts1le/)
>
> Edit: why the downvotes? Turns out there’s a mass pound as well as a weight pound, plus the English currency Pound.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is all links and I have difficulties parsing the train of thought. What are your own thoughts on it and what is *your* question? Please edit to add your own perspective and consider reducing the fraction of text that is a link. What do the links tell you and what's missing?

Comment: But I guess we can answer the titular question: *Libra* does not mean "weight."

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I wrote my question in the title — "Isn't lībra pondō pleonastic?"

Comment: I'd like to see an answer! The question seems clear enough to me: What's the story behind _lībra pondō_? Is it redundant? If not, how does it make grammatical and semantic sense?

Comment: I re-opened the questions since at least 3 users seem to want that. I should point out though that in OP answers his own question: "It was thought to represent scales or a balance, the main sense of *libra* in Latin, which is why it is often accompanied by the image of a pair of scales." This is one of the reasons why the actual question is unclear. But I'll leave the answering to others.

Answer (score 5):

*Libra pondo* means “weighing a *libra*,” and yes, it is redundant. We can see this because while we can see Romans writing things like:

- *argenti decem pondo libras habere* (A. Gellius)
- *libram pondo aeris valere* (Varro)

⋯ we *also* see many cases where they only say *libra* or only *pondo*:

- *libra ocellatorum* (Varro; an *ocellatum* is apparently some kind of gem or die)
- *corona aurea librarum quinque* (Suetonius)
- *auri quinque pondo* (Cicero)
- *argenti pondo viginti millia* (Caesar)

Let us look at the words individually:

- **libra** is the name of a Roman unit of weight, which is around 326 g (estimations for the exact value vary a few grams up and down). It is usually translated as “pound” (as are Romance words derived from it, e.g. French *livre*). It does not mean “weight” per se, but it generally unequivocally refers to a weight, so we do not necessarily have to specify that we are talking about weight.
- **pondo** is not, as Wikipedia says, simply “the ablative singular of the Latin noun *pondus*,” because that would be *pondere*. It is indeed understood as stemming from an ablative singular, but it is usually parsed as an adverb meaning “weighing, by weight.” As such, in principle, it has to go along with some quantity, e.g. *libra pondo*.

  However, if no unit is specified, it works as an undeclinable noun meaning pound or pounds. In effect, when a Roman says “gold weighing five” (*auri quinque pondo*), he means “five pounds of gold” (circa 1.6 kg). And this was a very common way to talk about weights. The English term “pound” (and others, e.g. German „Pfund“) are derived from it.

The way you phrased your question – isn't *libra pondo* pleonastic – suggests you are surprised the Romans would have used a redundant expression. But redundancy is very common throughout human speech. After all, “a bag weighing 5 kg” is also redundant, as the kilogram is a unit of weight, and it would suffice to say “a bag of 5 kg.”

Comment: +1, despite the physicist in me wanting to correct that kilogram is a unit of mass rather than weight. That's not a distinction worth making in this context, but I can't help bringing it up... // I'd go a step further and say that redundancy is not only common but also very useful. One should indeed not be surprised to see it in Latin.